# Relative homology of interlevel set

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, real-analysis

Let us consider a function $f:\mathbb{R}^3→\mathbb{R}$, 
$f(x,y,z)=x^3+y^3+z^3-5yz$. Can anybody drop a hint how 
to compute relative homology of interlevel sets with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}:
H_{\bullet}(f^{−1}(−∞,100),
f^{−1}(−∞,−100),\mathbb{R}).$

Comment: Dear @quantum: Can you say something about the background for this problem? For example, why you care and what you have tried?

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I work with last years variants of qualifying exams. I suppose that there is a general technique of calculation dimensions of these vector spaces. For instance, extended persistence diagrams (http://arxiv.org/pdf/1102.3389v1.pdf).